# How to calculate the performance of a filter when noise estimate is unknown

Tags: signal-processing

I have a noisy and filtered signal and I don't have an estimate of noise. Is the power of filtered and noisy signal a good estimate on how well the filter worked? Are there any other methods?

Answer (score 1):

The theoretical performance is easy enough to calculate or simulate. This would be my method of testing how good a filter *might* be.

As for extracting the noise level - subtract the clean signal from the noisy signal. It's called [SINAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SINAD) measurement.

If you say you don't have the clean signal then subtract the filtered signal from the unfiltered signal but you will be introducing errors and you'll need to optimize the amplitudes to get total signal cancellation or it won't work.

Comment: So ,is the power estimate of filtered signal and noisy signal signal a good estimate of filter performance?

Comment: SNR = signal to noise ratio and is very similar to SINAD and both are good methods of determining filter performance.